# Alamofire HTTP request with Python backend

Tags: python, ios, swift, httprequest

I have been stuck on this thing for a very long time, and I need help from you guys.

Try to use `Alamofire` to upload `POST` a picture to the back end, so that I can use that picture to get some result from my server.

my front code is

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController:UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate
{


    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        myImageUploadRequest()

    }



    @IBAction func selectPhotoButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])

    {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as?
        UIImage

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



    func myImageUploadRequest()
    {
        // convert image to data object
        guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1) else {
            print("Could not get JPEG representation of UIImage")
            return
        }

        // send multipart request
        Alamofire.upload( multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "imagefile", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")},

                          to: "http://123123123123/image",
                          encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                            // check the response
                            switch encodingResult {
                            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                upload.uploadProgress { progress in
                                    // Show progress
                                }
                                upload.responseJSON { response in
                                    // Handle response
                                }
                            case .failure(let encodingError):
                                print(encodingError)
                                // Handle Error
                            }
        })
    }
    }
```

My back end is

```
@app.route("/image", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def image():
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
    return '{ Success }' 

    file = request.files['file']
    img = Image.open(request.files['file'])
    img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
    return classify_image.pic_tensorflow('/templates/images/file.jpg')
```

So, I have been getting this error in the console for now:

> zechengpart[55172:9628252] [MC] Reading from private effective user
>   settings. 2018-03-13 02:50:01.108562-0500 zechengpart[55172:9628293]
>   [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error
>   Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

And I already fixed the infoplist issue about http not https.

When I ping the server, it gives me 
123.123.123.123 - - [13/Mar/2018 02:50:05] "POST /image HTTP/1.1" 400 -

How can I debug here to avoid that error info?

Please help, I am struggle with this for too long time.

Comment: I would personally try to upload the image using something like the Chrome Postman extension to make sure my backend is working properly first, then I would debug the iOS code.

Comment: At the very least, there's a syntax error on line 4 of the Python code you posted. The `return` after the `if` statement isn't indented to be in the `if`'s block. In fact, nothing is, so Python will raise an `IndentationError`

Comment: Hi man, my backend is working properly, because sometimes ago, my friend implement a android version of this app and send to the server, it works fine. It seems my front, there is a part that handling the picture might be some issues, but due to lack of the experience in swift, and also the online resource is kind of limited on the latest version, I am stuck here.

Comment: @MichaelHulet Hi man, thanks for the answer, but I am pretty sure this back end's function is working. In my understanding, if it is get, then success, if not, then it is post, you upload the image, then you will get results.

Comment: How do you know that your request is failing? Your code does not contain any `failure` block inside the `success` block for encoding

Comment: @Malik Hi man, thanks for asking. My request is sent to the server end, I did got a notification says,  [13/Mar/2018 02:50:05] "POST /image HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Comment: But on my console on the xcode, I did not get anything but that error message I just sent in the post. @Malik

Comment: Change your `success` block for encoding to

    `case .success(request: let upload, _, _):
        upload.validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
            switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Success")
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    break`

This would give you the error being returned from the server(if any). Once we have that information, we might be able to resolve it

Comment: @Malik thanks very much, I will try it now.

Comment: @Malik I added the code and run it again, it gives me "Response status code was unacceptable: 400."

Comment: This means that your server is returning an invalid status code in the response. Test your URL with `Postman` and see what status code is being returned by the server. But before that, remove `.validate()` from the code I posted earlier and see what error it returns

Comment: Or it could simply be an issue with the server side implementation where, for whatever reason, it is returning a 400 status code which means `Bad Request`

Comment: JSON could not be serialized because of error:
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: @Malik I get rid of the validate(), and I just got that. Does that mean the picture I send, is not the format my back end need?  Also, Would you please help me with this : [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Comment: I'm not much familiar with back end development. Besides, I have no idea what your back end implementation is like. As far as your front end code is concerned (specifically Alamofire), there is nothing wrong with that

Comment: @Malik thanks the same

Comment: @Malik hi man, would you please give me a contact information of you, So that I can send more details and questions? Do you have an email address?